# useWagmi and Nuxt3 mint function not working

Tags: wagmi

I have provided here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cgbkrw?file=pages%2Fhello.vue) a stackblitz recreation of the issue (although stackblitz seems to have trouble with the useWagmi module). This is using Nuxt3 and use-wagmi module. If someone can get stackblitz past that, I'm unsure what is not happening properly to use the **useContractWrite()** function. I keep getting the following three errors:

> ```
> vue-query composables like "uesQuery()" should only be used inside a "setup()" function or a running effect scope.
>
> [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components. at
>
> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler
> at <Pagename onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref< Proxy { : Proxy, : {…} }>>
> ```

Based on everything I've read and all of the examples I've gone through I have no idea what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.